# Can Symbolic Links span different file systems in Unix?

Tags: unix, symlink

Can Symbolic Links span different file systems in Unix or Linux

Comment: This should be posted to the [Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) website instead of StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  Hard  links cannot span file systems, soft links (symlinks) can.  And this was not a question that is really about programming.